# Is it possible to redirect or stop a subflows

Tags: flow

Is it possible to stop a subflow?

Simple example: a masterflow starts a subflow. In the subflow is a Decision. When the decision returns true, the subflow continues and eventually returns to the masterflow. When the decision returns false, the flow stops, and does not return to the masterflow.

Is this in any way configurable?